# Specifying /Controller vs. /controllers in config.xml

Tags: controllers

How do you specify that you want to use the /Controller folder instead of the /controllers folder within config.xml?

Answer (score 2):

You don't. The `controllers` directory is named like this for a good reason. The lowercased directories can not be accessed directly.

The `Controller` directory is usually used to define controller abstractions.